# About Vitali Convergence Theorem and Uniform Integrability

Tags: real-analysis

Are there any examples that we can apply Vitali convergence theorem but not dominated convergence theorem? I use dominated, monotone convergence theorems quite often. I would like to know is Vitali convergence theorem useful in practice (or just too general to be useful).

Another issue is that checking a sequence of functions is uniformly integrable from definition is very hard. Is there any simpler criterion to verify uniform integrability (except the sequence of functions are uniformly bounded, by then we can simply apply dominated/bounded convergence theorem)?

Comment: One question that popped up recently asked to show that $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$ if $f_n \to f$ pointwise and furthermore $\|f_n\|_{L^p} \leq C$ for all $n$, where $p>1$. In this case, you can apply Vitali (at least if the measure space is finite), but the dominated convergence theorem is not applicable in general. The same should hold for any function $\varphi$ satisfying $|\varphi(x)/x| \to \infty$ as $|x|\to\infty$ if we know $\int |\varphi(f_n (x))|\, d\mu(x) \leq C$ for all $n$ and $f_n \to f$ pointwise.

Answer (score 4):

On $[0,1]$ let

$$f_n = (2^n/n)\chi_{(1/2^n,1/2^{n-1})},\ \  n \in \mathbb N.$$
 Then $\int_0^1 f_n = 1/n \to 0,$ which implies $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable. We also have $f_n \to 0$ pointwise everywhere on $[0,1].$ Thus the hypotheses of Vitali are satisfied.

Suppose $g$ is measurable on $[0,1]$ and $f_n\le g$ for all $n.$ Then

$$\int_{1/2^n}^{1/2^{n-1}} g\ge  \int_{1/2^n}^{1/2^{n-1}} f_n\ge 1/n, \ n \in \mathbb N.$$

Hence $\int_0^1 g = \infty.$ Thus there is no dominating function in $L^1$ that works in the hypotheses of the DCT.

Comment: Could you explain why $\int_{0}^{1}g=\infty$? I didn't understand.

Comment: @VictorHugo  $$\int_0^1 g = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{1/2^n}^{1/2^{n-1}} g \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} =\infty.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!